# Creating external link from a splunk eventsviewer

Tags: javascript, splunk

Is it possible to create an events viewer field in splunk as clickable? How do you create a javascript for the same task, I want a clickable link in an events viewer field say `severity` to `www.google.com`.

How can I do that? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

For Splunk 5.0+, take a look at the [dynamic drilldowns for Splunk Dashboards](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Viz/Dynamicdrilldownindashboardsandforms) example. You can create dynamic links based upon data in your results using a simple XML forms table.

```xml
<dashboard>
  <label>Demo: drilldown</label>
  <row>
    <table>
      <searchString>
        index=foursquare checkin.primarycategory.nodename=*
        | spath output=venue path=checkin.venue.name
        | spath output=badges path=checkin.badges{}.name
        | eval link="Yelp Search"
        | stats count as checkins sparkline values(badges)
              as "badges" values(link) as "links" by venue
        | sort -checkins
      </searchString>

      <format field="sparkline" type="sparkline">
        <option name="type">bar</option>
        <option name="height">30</option>
        <option name="barColor">green</option>
        <option name="colorMap">
          <option name="5:9">yellow</option>
          <option name="10:">red</option>
        </option>
      </format>
      <title>Top Venues</title>
      <drilldown>

        <!-- Mulitvalue field drilldown -->
        <link field="badges">
         /app/foursquare_vegas/vegas_badge_1?form.badge=$click.value2$
        </link>

        <link field="venue">
          /app/foursquare_vegas/vegas_venue_1?form.venue=$row.venue$
        </link>
        <link field="links">
          http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=$row.venue$&find_loc=Las+Vegas,+NV
        </link>
      </drilldown>

    </table>
  </row>  
</dashboard>
```

If this example doesn't achieve what you are after - you can always [hook into the JS events using `NullModule`](http://dev.splunk.com/view/app-framework/SP-CAAAEE2) or invest some effort into learning [SideView Utils integration](http://sideviewapps.com/apps/sideview-utils/).

Comment: Thank you SilverNinja,, but how can i do it in events viewer itself, instead of a table display

Comment: By **events viewer**, do you mean the **flashtimeline** dashboard?

Comment: yes exactly... In flash timeline after my search, the result should be displayed in events viewer with one of the field say severity with a clickable link to google or KB document etc...

Answer (score 0):

The closest answer out of the box would be workflow actions, which would not be in the result table itself, but just before the event. Take a look at the [docs](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.0.1/Knowledge/CreateworkflowactionsinSplunkWeb) for more. For formatting it exactly how you want, you would need to use [sideview utils](http://apps.splunk.com/app/1486/), which would make it easy to do via embedding search results in their HTML control